# Adding end-to-end TLS to an Azure App Service behind Azure Front Door

Tags: security, dns, azure

We've got a web application (C#/.Net Core) hosted on an Azure App Service. The app service's access restrictions are configured to only allow access via Azure Front Door.

The Front Door is set up with custom subdomains that route to the App Service backend.

For the application to function correctly, it needs to know what URL it's being accessed at (we have to generate absolute URLs that are user-facing, but they should be based on the URL the user is accessing it at.)

As a summary:

- myapp.company.com has a CNAME DNS entry pointing to Azure Front Door (myfrontdoor.azurefd.net).
- Front Door listens on myapp.mycompany.com as a frontend domain. Front Door manages a TLS/SSL cert for this subdomain.
- Front Door routes traffic from myapp.mycompany.com to the Azure App Service (myapp.azurewebsites.net). The "backend host header" field is set to the URL that the user uses to access the site (myapp.mycompany.com).
- Because the code running on the app service needs to know what URL the user is using to access it (e.g. it needs to be accessed via myapp.mycompany.com instead of myapp.azurewebsites.net), the custom subdomain is added as a "custom domain" in the App Service configuration. If this isn't done, the app service doesn't accept the connections from Front Door, because it doesn't send the default host header (myapp.azurewebsites.net).

This configuration is functional - the web app running on the app service can tell that it's being accessed via the custom domain (myapp.mycompany.com).

However, in this configuration, I can't add a TLS/SSL cert to the app service's custom domain. This functionality in Azure relies on DNS verification - the custom subdomain must have a CNAME record that points to the app service default URL (myapp.azurewebsites.net) in order to create the certificate. But, the subdomain CNAME needs to point to Front Door (myfrontdoor.azurefd.net) in order for Front Door to manage the certificate on the front-end.

The Azure portal page for the app service complains about the fact that the custom domain's "SSL State" is "Not Secure" because of this, and it does reduce security - the communication between Front Door to the app service isn't actually secured by a certificate.

Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: How would Front Door be able to function if it can't intercept the requests made to the app?

Comment: @user1686 It does intercept. But, I want to do end-to-end TLS, where the Front Door -> App Service connection is also secured by TLS. The wrinkle is that the app service needs to know about the front-end domain name.

Comment: does this help? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/concept-end-to-end-tls